# Реализация инструкции include

Tags: php

Написал простой код: include.php

```
<?php
include "settings.php"; 
$c = $a+$b;
echo "Сума переменных - $c";
?>
```

В файле settings.php как положено создал 2 переменные с некоторыми значениями:

```
<?php 
$a = 10;
$b = 15;
?>
```

Но в результате ничего не получилось - при запуске include.php - в браузере ничего не отобразилось. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся? Спасибо.

Comment: Итак, что-то не ту вас с php :) Давайте по порядку: какая у вас ОС? какой веб-сервер? какая версия php? каким образом вы подключали php к веб-серверу? Проверяли ли вы на более простых примерах работоспособность связки php и веб-сервера?

Comment: не знаю, стоит ли все описывать, так как буквально предыдущий пример (урок, так сказать)) прошел без проблем. А пользуюсь я Денвер'ом 3 со всеми вытекающими последствиями. но в голове не укладывается, как такой простой код может не работать...

Comment: Хм, попробуйте предыдущий пример еще раз, заработает ли он? Ну и советы: если вы пользуетесь firefox, то нажмите Ctrl+F5 (вероятно вы смотрите на страничку из кэша браузера, в других браузерах к сожалению не знаю как сбросить кэш для текущей страницы), перезапустите денвер, перезагрузите компьютер, переустановите денвер. Проделайте в том порядке, что я написал и каждый раз проверяйте не заработало ли.

Comment: уже успел проверить. все примеры работают, Денвер перазагружал... щас комп перезагружу. использую Оперу. в любом случае, спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//settings
<?php
$a = 10;
$b = 15;
?>
//include
<?php
include('settings.php');
$c = $a + $b;
echo 'Сума переменных - '.$c;
?>
```

И совет, пользуйтесь как можно реже includ'ом.

Comment: К сожалению, так тоже не получается. К совету прислушаюсь, только можете обьяснить, почему?

Comment: include() сильно нагружает веб сервер, а работает она так :

php читает ваш код, доходит до include, выполняет файл, который подключается через include, заново проходит по вашему коду, заменяет include на результат выполнения подключаемого файла и идёт дальше по коду.

Comment: Наверно имеется в виду, что надо использовать require_once(""); Инклюдом можно случайно запутавшись понавключать один файл кучу раз так, что будет невозможно понять, где что сколько раз включается. А require_once можно писать в начале любого скрипта не боясь, что он уже был включён где-то выше.

Comment: Обо всех функциях уж достаточно хорошо расписано на php.su, читайте.

Comment: @Kremchik, есть функцию include_once. @Андрей Аршинов, 'include() сильно нагружает веб сервер' - бред, вы еще посоветуйте все в один фаил сложить. При включенном расширении кэширования опкода стоимость операции инклюда не более операции вызова функции. Даже если кэш опкода не включен файловая система подгрузить и будет удерживать в памяти часто используемые файлы. auto_load - другая песня

Comment: Ну вот и объясняйте, кеп.

Comment: @Glagola, да, точно =) Только include_once в отличие от require_once не остановит скрипт в случае, если такого файла нету. Поэтому лучше использовать require_once для подключения функций, классов и пр.

Comment: "Ну вот и объясняйте, кеп.", а где указано, что include() нагружает сервер? На w3schools и десятке других ресурсов написано, что отличие только в том, что include не останавливает скрипт в случае ошибки.

Comment: @Kremchik, спасибо не знал такой особенности у этой парочки :)

Comment: в любом случае, спасибо всем участникам за помощь) узнал много нового.

Comment: @Kremchik, еще есть отличие что include может вернуть результат (если в скрипте, который подключают есть return), соответственно его можно использовать в условных выражениях.

Comment: А у меня сейчас и require вернул =) Тот же код, что в вопросе, только в конце settings.php я добавил return 177. А в include.php написал в конце echo "< br />" . require 'settings.php'; Выдало.